# jquery if statement to check if element is within a specific parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, parent, children

I have alot of elements with class of .button all over my layout. Upon a click of the element with class of button, I need to check first that the element is within the parent div of either box1 or box2.

A short example would be... if the clicked button is within the box1 div && (another condition) then do something.  Would it be best to use the combination of .closet and .length to check if the button is within a certain div?

```
<div id="box1">
        <div id="column1">
             <div class="round_button"></div>
             <div style="background: #000">
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
 <div> 

<div id="box2">
        <div id="column2">
             <div class="round_button"></div>
             <div style="background: #000">
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
                  <div class="button"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the answer above, if there are a number of buttons, and instead of binding an event separately to each, you just want to attach once, based upon its ancestor, you can do something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is("#box1 *")) {}
});
```

Comment: @undefined, I can't find any. Where do you think is the error?

Comment: @Cupidvogel There is an extra `(`.

Comment: @user1502434, When the button is clicked, you check whether this button is any one of the descendants of the element with id `box1`, if so, you take a certain action. This check is done by `if (($(this).is("#box1 *"))`.

Comment: great, I think this will be my preferred approach! Very nice.

Comment: How does this compare with `if($(this).closest("#box1").length)` in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Good one. It is difficult to say which one is more efficient, but it looks like this might be the one, here the search would stop when the selector mentioned in `closest` is encountered, whereas in my solution, first all the children of the parent element are converted into jQuery objects, then a search is made among them for the element in question. So most probably this one would be more efficient, although it would hardly matter.

Comment: _"first all the children of the parent element are converted into jQuery objects"_ - Not quite right. You'd get a single jQuery object containing all those matching elements... But yes, that's why I thought it would be less efficient. Won't matter much in this example with a small amount of html, but in larger cases it could be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

If the functionality between the two groups of buttons differs significantly, I would just define event handlers on each group of buttons:

```
$('#box1 .button').on('click', function(event) {
  // ...
});

$('#box2 .button').on('click', function(event) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `if statement` if there is no else.

```
$('#box1, #box2').find('.button').click(function() {
  //  do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).parents("#box1");` inside the click event function for the buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box1 .button').click(function() {
  // first code
});

$('#box2 .button').click(function() {
  // second code
});
```